# How can I run microk8s on LXD?

Tags: lxd, microk8s

When I try to `snap install microk8s` on an LXD machine, it doesn't start and produces these errors:

```
sysop@hoseplavm:~$ lxc list
+------------+---------+----------------------+------+------------+-----------+
|    NAME    |  STATE  |         IPV4         | IPV6 |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+------------+---------+----------------------+------+------------+-----------+
| kubernetes | RUNNING | 10.144.28.123 (eth0) |      | PERSISTENT |           |
+------------+---------+----------------------+------+------------+-----------+
sysop@hoseplavm:~$ lxc exec kubernetes bash
root@kubernetes:~# microk8s.inspect
Inspecting services
Service snap.microk8s.daemon-containerd is running
Service snap.microk8s.daemon-apiserver is running
FAIL:  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-proxy is not running
For more details look at: sudo journalctl -u snap.microk8s.daemon-proxy
FAIL:  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet is not running
For more details look at: sudo journalctl -u snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet
Service snap.microk8s.daemon-scheduler is running
Service snap.microk8s.daemon-controller-manager is running
Service snap.microk8s.daemon-etcd is running
Copy service arguments to the final report tarball
Inspecting AppArmor configuration
Gathering system info
Copy network configuration to the final report tarball
Copy processes list to the final report tarball
Copy snap list to the final report tarball
Inspect kubernetes cluster

Building the report tarball
Report tarball is at /var/snap/microk8s/522/inspection-report-20190604_133500.tar.gz
root@kubernetes:~#
```

Is it possible to install microk8s inside an LXD container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to run MicroK8s in LXD with the right profiles. Have a look at https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/tree/master/tests/lxc . Our testing across different distributions uses lxc containers.

Note that the profiles above grant too wide privileges. This is something we intend to address in the future.